# How do I get Leanback's details fragment to not take up the whole screen?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-tv, leanback

On the Google Play Movies app, when you focus on the details fragment, it leaves some space at the bottom so that you can see the rows beneath it. When using the LeanBack library, there isn't this space, the details fragment takes up the whole screen. How do we make it behave like in the Google Play Movies app?

Comment: Can you post a photo explaining what you mean more specifically?

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/cq7iC

Red screen is Google Play Movies, blue screen is my app. I was wondering how I could make my movie details fragment work like the Google Play Movies app with the space at the bottom.

Comment: @ygu Did you find the solution? I have the same problem>

Answer (score 3):

Override the following dimension from the Leanback support library by adding it to your res/values/dimens.xml file:

`<dimen name="lb_details_v2_card_height">470dp</dimen>`

You can set the height of the card. By default, it's 540dp, which fills the height of the display (for example, 1280 x 720 pixels at TVDPI (1.33x) = 540dp in height).

Comment: lb_details_v2_card_height changing it changes the card height but the related vidoes are still invisible

Comment: reduce the height to around 350 dp, it worked for me. The experiment can be done with minimum height 20-30 dp also

Comment: how to programmatically do this? setting it in dimens.xml will result in all DetailsFragment having this behavior. I wish to use it in a specific fragment.

Comment: @chitgoks Use a theme and override the value in that specific theme.